# Angular Factory Service Issue, Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, service

The generator I used to set up my angular project has everything coded in short hand and distributed oddly so I'm working through trying to get my old project into their form so when I build it the project will deploy my scripts correctly.

So my current issue is that I had my controllers in my old project communicating with each other to pass a id from my main controller to my gallery controller. I did this all through a parent controller. Now when I make the leap to this new format it seems that it wont work the same way and I should probably use a service instead.

With all this being said I'm having a problem with my service through my current set up. For what ever reason no matter what I do my service isn't defined in my project. I realized my project injector is placing my service file behind my controller files for what ever reason I figured this would be the issue but I tried placing the code with in my routes file and still had the problem.

If someone could look over my code and check whats wrong and maybe even give me a little insight on how to pass a ID from my main to my gallery I'd be very grateful!

Thanks

Service.js

```
(function() {
```

'use strict';

angular
    .module('bhamDesign')
    .factory('mainService', mainService)

function mainService(){
    var main;

```
var mainService = {
  setMain: function(input) {
    main = input;
  },
  getMain: function() {
    return main;
  }
    };
    return mainServices;
  }

})();
```

Module.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('bhamDesign', ['ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAria', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'mm.foundation']);

})();
```

Route.js

```
    (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('bhamDesign')
    .config(routerConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .state('gallery', {
        url: '/mainId',
        templateUrl: 'app/gallery/gallery.html',
        controller: 'GalleryController',
        controllerAs: 'gallery'
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }

})();
```

MainController.js

```
    (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('bhamDesign')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

  function MainController($scope, mainService, $http, $state) {

  $http.get('../../assets/json/projects.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.mains = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = '-year';

  $scope.setId = function(){
    mainServices.setMain($scope.id);
    $state.go('gallery');
  };
}

})();
```

GalleryController.js

```
    (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('bhamDesign')
    .controller('GalleryController', GalleryController);

  function GalleryController($scope, $state, $http) {
    $http.get('.../.../assets/json/galleries/' + mainServices.getMain() + '.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.gallery = data;
    });
  }

})();
```

Main.html

```
    .row
  .small-12.medium-3.columns.left(ng-repeat="main in mains | orderBy:orderProp | filter:categoryFilter:true")
    .thumbnail-container   
      a(ng-click="setId")
        img.thumbnail(ng-src="{{main.thumbnail}}")
        .text 
          h5 {{main.title}}
          h6 {{main.year}}
```

Error Message

```
ReferenceError: mainServices is not defined
    at Object.mainService (http://localhost:3000/app/index.service.js:19:12)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4604:19)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4443:37)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4604:19)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4403:37
    at getService (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4550:39)
    at injectionArgs (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4574:58)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4616:18)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9870:28
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:4081:28 <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13236(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9965invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:9494nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8978compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:8226publicLinkFn @ angular.js:8106(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8447updateView @ angular-ui-router.js:4021(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.js:3959Scope.$broadcast @ angular.js:17143$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition @ angular-ui-router.js:3352processQueue @ angular.js:15552(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15568Scope.$eval @ angular.js:16820Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16636Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16928done @ angular.js:11266completeRequest @ angular.js:11464requestLoaded @ angular.js:11405
```

Comment: Posting all your code is not necessary. What is necessary is the complete and exact error message.

Comment: Sorry, I added the error message to the end.

Comment: Hm, I'm using gulp to inject my scripts into my html but I checked network panel and all that seems fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
angular.module('bhamDesign').factory(mainService);
```

This is incorrect. You didn't specify the name of the service. It should be

```
angular.module('bhamDesign').factory('mainService', mainService);
```

Comment: Got it, I had that at one point and it was still drawing an error. I just changed it back and its seems to be drawing a different but similar ReferenceError: mainServices is not defined error. I'll update my code and error to reflect it.

Comment: No need. You're returning `mainServices` instead of `mainService`.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks so much. I always kick myself when I spend so much time troubleshooting and it ends up being a stupid typo...

Comment: do you mind explaining to me how I could transfer the mainId from my mainController to my galleryController with the services? The tutorial I was using used ng-click to transfer to a specific page but I want to be able to pull a specific id and transfer to its correlating gallery page with ui-sref.

Comment: You shouldn't use a service to do that. The id of the main to display should be in the URL. You should pass it as a parameter in $state.go(). You should have it in the URL in the gallery state configuration. and you should get it from $stateParams in the gallery controller. Think about it: if the user is on the gallery page and refreshes the page, where will the gallery controller find the ID to load if it's not in the URL? No main ID will be available in the mainService, since the user didn't go to the main page before.

Comment: Got it, sometimes I make things more difficult for myself. I went back to what I originally had and you suggested and it works fine. Thanks again.